# Python Tkinter: how to get text from ScrolledText widget on <Destroy> event callback?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I understand ScrolledText is constructed as a Text object (but has a scrollbar attached together in a frame). But the following code throws an error when the window is closed and the `printText()` method is called:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import ScrolledText as st
class tkGui(object):
    def printText(self, event):
        print "It works!"
        self.mText.get("1.0", 'end-1c')

    def __init__(self, window):
        # create widgets
        self.frame=tk.Frame(window)
        self.mText = st.ScrolledText(self.frame)
        self.mText.bind('<Destroy>',self.printText)
        # place widgets
        self.frame.pack()
        self.mText.pack()

window = tk.Tk()
app = tkGui(window)
window.mainloop()
```

The error:

```
[...]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3077, in get
  return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
TclError: invalid command name ".140506094171344.140506094172280.140506094172496"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you destroy the main window, all its sub-widgets are destroyed, and you can't access them.  (This is not technically correct, as Bryan Oakley's answer points out, but it's how I think about it.  Trying to work with the widgets after destruction is problematical, at best.)

You need to use `wm_protocol`

http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.Tk.wm_protocol

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import ScrolledText as st
class tkGui(object):
    def printText(self):
        print "It works!"
        self.mText.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        self.window.destroy()

    def __init__(self, window):
        # create widgets
        self.window = window
        self.frame=tk.Frame(window)
        self.mText = st.ScrolledText(self.frame)
        #self.mText.bind('<Destroy>',self.printText)
        window.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.printText)
        # place widgets
        self.frame.pack()
        self.mText.pack()

window = tk.Tk()
app = tkGui(window)
window.mainloop()
```

There are a couple of changes here.  I removed the `event` parameter from `printText` and added a call to `self.window.destroy`.  Note that I had to add the `self.window` attribute to make this call.  The basic change is using wm_protocol instead of binding to the  event; the others are necessary consequences.

Answer (score 2):

You should not assume you can get data out of a widget when handling the `<Destroy>` event for that widget.

From the official documentation:

> When the Destroy event is delivered to a widget, it is in a
>   “half-dead” state: the widget still exists, but most operations on it
>   will fail.

Comment: @DhaLee: what do you mean "unreliably"? The widget is destroyed, why should you be able to interact with a deleted object?

Comment: @DhaLee: you can use it, you just can't use it to get attributes of the destroyed object. Most often this is used to do some clean-up of related data. This event has had this behavior for _decades_ and nobody has complained about it. It simply wasn't designed for the purpose you wish it had been designed for. If your goal is to save the contents of a window when it is being destroyed, there are better ways that are specifically created for that purpose (see the other answer that mentions `wm_protocol`)